# Taylor polynomial $P(n)$ of $f$ at $x_0$.

Tags: real-analysis

True or False: if $P(n)$ is the $n^{th}$ Taylor polynomial for $f$ at a point $x_0$, then the first $n$ derivatives of $P(n)$ and $f$ are equal at $x_0$.

Answer (score 3):

$$f(x)=\underbrace{f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+\frac{f''(x_0)(x-x_0)^2}{2!}+\ldots +\frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)(x-x_0)^n}{n!}}_{=Pn}+ R_n(x_0)$$

$$P_n'=f'(x_0)+f''(x_0)(x-x_0)+\ldots+\frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)(x-x_0)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\implies P'_n(x_0)=f'(x_0)$$

and we've showed the claim for the first derivative at $\;x_0\;$. Try now to generalize the above for the other derivatives.